# Is it \limsup or \lim\sup?

Tags: math-mode

Is the concept of limit superior in mathematics written as `$\limsup$` or `$\lim\sup$`?

Comment: This site doesn't render latex formula, does it?

Comment: No, and quite deliberately so (we are usually interested in the code). I've marked up your input as such using `\``.

Comment: No LaTeX rendering indeed. The limit superior is usually denotes as `\limsup`. The `\lim` and `\sup` are there because these are also concepts on their own. Using `\limsup` you are ensured of correct spacing. Furthermore, using `limits` notation `\limsup` ensures the lower limit is set centered under the entire word, this would be troublesome with `\lim\sup`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think my comment answers the question quite well, so I will just add it as an answer. The most important part to me is the limit placement. So:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  $\limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow0}$ vs $\lim\sup\limits_{x\rightarrow0}$ 
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: limsup vs lim sup]

So you will want to use `\limsup`.